# English word for superstitiously negative self assumption

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, expressions, speech, negative-polarity-items

Is there an English word (or psychological condition), which describes the negative, fearful, superstitious mentality of immediate self application or assumption?

For example if I was to say "my grandfather has been diagnosed with cancer", then their internal response may be "I'll probably get cancer".

Comment: It's called a mix of "shock", and *self-absorption*

Comment: Hypocondria perhaps, in this context.

Comment: ***Irrational belief:*** http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/schools/psychology/centres/rebt/about/beliefs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Valetudinarian**

Oxford English Dictionary:

> A person who is *unduly* anxious about their health.